# Get selected value from drop down Laravel 4

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

I want to get the selected value from a drop down list in a controller method.
The drop down list :

```
{{ Form::select('Organization',  $organization_list ,Input::old('Organization'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

$organization_list is an array of organizations..
I have tried to catch the selected item of this drop down list in a controller as follows:

```
Input::get('Organization');
```

But it gives me the array index instead of the real organization name..But the real organization name is shown in drop down list.. does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an associative array To `Form::select` as the second argument

```
$organization_list = array_combine($organization_list, $organization_list); //Copies the array values to keys


{{ Form::select('Organization',  $organization_list ,Input::old('Organization'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

http://php.net/array-combine